# interpreting PERMANOVA (adonis function) output?

Tags: r, regression, matrix, ecology

I am trying to look at expression of some genes and relate the dist matrix (Sm) to a number of different factors that I collected on the individuals (e.g., litter size, licking behavior, group housing conditions). Housing conditions are categorical while licking and litter size are continuous.

```
> adonis(Sm ~ licking + litsiz + grp, data=sub7)

Call:
adonis(formula = Sm ~ licking + litsiz + grp, data = sub7) 

Permutation: free
Number of permutations: 999

Terms added sequentially (first to last)

          Df SumsOfSqs MeanSqs F.Model      R2 Pr(>F)  
licking    1    1.1831 1.18312  3.7850 0.20868  0.025 *
litsiz     1    0.4898 0.48976  1.5668 0.08639  0.185  
grp        2    1.4959 0.74796  2.3928 0.26386  0.042 *
Residuals  8    2.5007 0.31258         0.44108         
Total     12    5.6695                 1.00000         
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

I notice that when I change the order of the variables, I get different results. This is expected since terms are added sequentially (Type I SS).

```
> adonis(Sm ~ licking + grp + litsiz, data=sub7)

Call:
adonis(formula = Sm ~ licking + grp + litsiz, data = sub7) 

Permutation: free
Number of permutations: 999

Terms added sequentially (first to last)

          Df SumsOfSqs MeanSqs F.Model      R2 Pr(>F)  
licking    1    1.1831 1.18312  3.7850 0.20868  0.020 *
grp        2    1.3785 0.68924  2.2050 0.24314  0.081 .
litsiz     1    0.6072 0.60720  1.9425 0.10710  0.157  
Residuals  8    2.5007 0.31258         0.44108         
Total     12    5.6695                 1.00000         
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

I can't seem to wrap my head around how to interpret these results? Is this an incorrect way to analyze these data?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you clarify what you do & don't understand here? You say you understand type I SS, what is it about the interpretation you aren't getting?

Comment: @gung - I don't understand the interpretation with 3 variables. Based on the output above, what would you conclude about my data?

Comment: Are you wondering whether, & which, variables are related to the response, & which ordering is the right ordering to use?

Comment: @gung - yes, what are your thoughts?

Comment: @gung - do you know if there is a way to go from SS Type I to SS Type II/III?

Comment: Not sure if you can use a PERMANOVA with continuous variables

Comment: It was a long time ago, but may can help other ones that are looking for the same answer. https://github.com/vegandevs/vegan/issues/231